# Using Wayland on my Debian upgraded system

Tags: desktop-environment, wayland

So I just installed the latest Kali Linux on my laptop which was based on what is currently an oldstable. I then upgraded the whole thing to current stable, which then upgraded my Gnome Desktop to version 3...

Coincidentally, Wayland just had a working package in the Debian repository on the current stable. How do I use it?

When I boot up I get shown this screen (which it didn't do in the Gnome 2 of the latest Kali):
https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/files/2013/09/login-screen.png

Then I select the Setting (the gear on the left side of "Sign In" button). It shows me:

`System Default`

`Gnome`

`Gnome Classic`

`Gnome on Wayland`

The only one that's ever worked was `Gnome Classic`. How do I force the usage of Wayland? I already have these Wayland related packages installed:

`xwayland`

`weston`

`ibus-wayland`

`libwayland-client0`

`libwayland-server`

`libwayland-egl1-mesa`

`libwayland-cursor0`

`libva-wayland1`

Yet when I choose `Gnome on Wayland`, the screen gets screwed up... How do I enter Wayland?

Btw, the file ~/.config/weston.ini does not exist.

Comment: Try updating to Gnome 3.20.